# How to convert string to XML using C#

Tags: c#, xml

Global variable `m_xDoc`

I have a property of

```
public XmlDocument xDoc
{
    get {return m_xDoc; }
    set {value = m_xDoc; }           
} 

string xml = "<head><body><Inner> welcome </head></Inner><Outer> Bye</Outer></body></head>"
```

Now I have to set that property with this string as XML document ... please guide me how to do this

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Use LoadXml Method of XmlDocument;

```
string xml = "<head><body><Inner> welcome </head> </Inner> <Outer> Bye</Outer></body></head>";
xDoc.LoadXml(xml);
```

Comment: can you please see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55440649/unable-to-get-values-from-soap-response-using-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment97598706_55440649) regarding this ?

Comment: Nice and easy! Thxs

Answer (score 40):

```
// using System.Xml;

String rawXml =
      @"<root>
          <person firstname=""Riley"" lastname=""Scott"" />
          <person firstname=""Thomas"" lastname=""Scott"" />
      </root>";

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(rawXml);
```

I think this should work.

Comment: Just as a note, you need to escape the quotes in order to compile that code, to escape them use double quotes (""). `<person firstname=""Riley"" lastname=""Scott"" />`

Comment: You're absolutely right. I forget about the double quotes inside the string. Corrected that.

Answer (score 20):

```
string test = "<body><head>test header</head></body>";

XmlDocument xmltest = new XmlDocument();
xmltest.LoadXml(test);

XmlNodeList elemlist = xmltest.GetElementsByTagName("head");

string result = elemlist[0].InnerXml; 

//result -> "test header"
```

Comment: What if this test header has some special characters like < or >?

Answer (score 5):

```
xDoc.LoadXML("<head><body><Inner> welcome </head> </Inner> <Outer> Bye</Outer>                    
                    </body></head>");
```